# Spring map merge all values

Tags: java, spring

I have two maps defined through `<util:map>` (one is to be used, the other is a reference map to be used by others). I want to refernce (import/merge) the values of one map into the other ie

```
CommonMap
    -> "someKey"      : "someValue"
    -> "someOtherKey" : "someOtherValue"

Map1
    -> grab all key value pairs in 'CommonMap'
```

I have tried a simpler example of defining the common map and trying to reference it for property injection:

**EDIT #2 Initial problem resolved thanks to answers below and now the main issue**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">

   <bean id="mainBean" class="SpringTest.SpringTest">
          <property name="myBean" ref="myFirstBean"/>
   </bean>

   <bean id="myFirstBean" class="SpringTest.MyBean">
          <constructor-arg value="Hello!"/>
          <property name="myMap" ref="myLookup" />
   </bean>

   <util:map id="myLookup">
          <entry key="myKey" value="142"/>
          <entry key="myOtherKey" value="7"/>
   </util:map>
```

How do I create a second `<map>` and reference all the values of `myLookup` in it?

**EDIT #3 more detail on what I have tried**

Trying this

```
<bean id="myFirstBean" class="SpringTest.MyBean">
          <constructor-arg value="Hello!"/>
          <property name="myMap" ref="myLookup" />
   </bean>

   <util:map id="commonLookup">
          <entry key="myKey" value="142"/>
          <entry key="myOtherKey" value="7"/>
   </util:map>

   <bean id="myLookup" parent="commonLookup">
          <util:map merge="true" />
   </bean>
```

but get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 25 in XML document from class path resource [configuration-spring.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 25; columnNumber: 40; cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'merge' is not allowed to appear in element 'util:map'.
```

Comment: Can you post your xml entry for `xmlns:util`

Comment: xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"

Comment: Have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12226551/3898076

Comment: Thanks, now how do i merge these values into a second map?

Comment: What problem you are getting now?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243376/how-to-merge-multiple-maps-into-one-in-spring

Comment: Do google for merge using util:map and see what you are getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/13243395/3817953:

```
<bean id="myFirstBean" class="SpringTest.MyBean">
    <constructor-arg value="Hello!" />
    <property name="myMap" ref="myLookup" />
</bean>

<bean id="commonLookup" 
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MapFactoryBean">
    <property name="sourceMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="myKey" value="142" />
            <entry key="myOtherKey" value="7" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="myLookup" parent="commonLookup" 
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MapFactoryBean">
    <property name="sourceMap">
        <map merge="true">
            <entry key="myLookupKey" value="12" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ensure the `util` namespace declaration is fully defined in the `beans` tag in the application context file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">
```